# bash - source without polluting own namespace [get variables from other scripts in a safe manner]

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'd like to assign the contents of variables of another bash script to variables in the calling script.

Specifically, I `source` this file: https://projects.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/plain/trunk/PKGBUILD?h=packages/firefox (and other alike files).

The file contains variables named `depends`, `makedepends`, etc.

So in my script I have multiple statements like these:

```
depends="$(source "/path/to/file" ; printf '%s' "${depends[@]}")"
makedepends="$(source "/path/to/file" ; printf '%s' "${makedepends[@]}")"
...
```

So basically, each statement starts it's own subshell which sources the file and prints the contents of **just ONE variable** to a variable in the parent shell.

**Is there another way which involves to start just a SINGLE subshell**, source the file and get the contents of specified variables of the file assigned to specified variables in the calling shell **without polluting the environment of the calling shell?**

### ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Since Mark Mann pointed out the dangers of `source`-ing foreign scripts, I ended up with another solution. Instead of using `source` to get variables of another script, one can use a multi line `grep` with a `perl` regex to grep all needed variables from the file (varName=(...),varName2="...",varname3='...',varName4=...) and `eval` the result:

```
$ grepvars='(license)|(depends)|(makedepends)|(url)|(pkgdesc)|(pkgver)'
$
$ eval $(grep -Pzo "^(${grepvars})=\([^\)\(\`]*\)|^(${grepvars})=\"[^\"\(\`]*\"|^(${grepvars})='\''[^'\'']*'\''|^(${grepvars})=[^\s;\(\`]*" /tmp/above_mentioned_file)
$ echo $url
https://www.mozilla.org/firefox/
$
$ echo ${depends[@]}
gtk3 gtk2 mozilla-common libxt startup-notification mime-types dbus-glib alsa-lib ffmpeg2.8 desktop-file-utils hicolor-icon-theme libvpx icu libevent nss hunspell sqlite ttf-font
```

Comment: You could source it in a subshell that does all the commands that require those variables.  Is there a big problem with having those variables in the calling shell though?  Will the mess up future steps or something?

Comment: This is a general question to improve my bash code - I treat it like this: I assume, each file I source directly in the parent shell will possibly overwrite variables in the parent shell. Also, basically all follow up code in the specific script depends on the information retrieved from the file.

Comment: That's true that they will overwrite existing variables, but I don't think your proposed approach is going to make for better scripting.  If you have that much data to manage, perhaps it's time to move to a more traditional programming language instead of a shell

Comment: You may be right that this is better to be handled by python, perl, etc. :)

Comment: @MCH: No, the `grep` solution doesn't mitigate the problem.  Imagine a line that reads `url=http://example.com; rm -rf $HOME`.   If you want to be safe we should probably parse the file directly.

Comment: Actually it **does** mitigate the problem, it only matches `url=http://example.com;` - I tried it.

Comment: There's a problem though, it also matches `url=http://example.com;echo` I'll try to fix that

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `eval`.

If you have your source (in /tmp/other.sh):

```
a=1
b=2
c=3
```

And you want only a portion, you can use `eval` to get just those items (here in /tmp/main.sh):

```
eval $(source /tmp/other.sh;
       echo a="$a";
       echo b="$b";)

echo a is $a "(expect 1)"
echo b is $b "(expect 2)"
echo c is $c "(expect nothing)"
```

And running it:

```
$ bash /tmp/main.sh
a is 1 (expect 1)
b is 2 (expect 2)
c is (expect nothing)
```

**WARNING**: Performing an `eval` or `source` on an untrusted script is very dangerous.  You're executing a shell script, and that script can perform anything you could do yourself. **WARNING**

Comment: This only works if the values don't contain any shell special character. You can make this robust, but it requires some effort.

Comment: Well now I'm interested! How can you make this robust --- why isn't this robust?

Comment: Are you saying, I need to escape all shell special chars before eval?

Comment: As soon as you're executing `source` against a foreign script, you're in very dangerous territory.  Escaping the actual values matters little if the script has a `rm -rf $HOME`.  Updating answer to reflect this.

Comment: You're obviously right - tbh I didn't even think of `rm -rf $HOME` :) So `eval`  `cat` script in subshell ?!? :)

Comment: I updated my question with another personal solution not involving `source`. Do you think this is reasonably safe now?

Comment: Can I get rid of inner `echo` in `eval` call? Can I assign it some other way?

Comment: What if those lines contain multiple words, like `NAME="CentOS Linux"` in /etc/os-release?

Answer (score 3):

Without using `eval` you can still do this via process substitution if you're using `bash` or similar:

```
source <(source "/path/to/file" ; printf %s\\n "depends=${depends[*]}" "makedepends=${makedepends[*]}")
```

This starts a subshell and sources the file, just like your initial example, but then instead of directly printing the value and using command substitution, it prints the value formatted as an assignment and sources the output using process substitution.

This exactly answers the following part of your question:

> Is there another way which involves to start just a SINGLE subshell, source the file and get the contents of specified variables of the file assigned to specified variables in the calling shell without polluting the environment of the calling shell?

But of course **the dangers of sourcing foreign scripts still apply.  Don't source an untrusted script, ever.**

If you wrote the script yourself and you are *absolutely sure* it has no side effects (and produces no output) then you could use the above for *your own personal computer*.  It's not something that should *ever* be in a production script.  Very very big security hole.

Comment: Running `source "/path/to/file"` will still execute any commands found in that file.  This is the root of the insecurity.  I've amended my comments above.

Comment: @MarkMann, absolutely correct.  I will edit my answer to emphasize that point.  I just wanted to provide the alternate answer; I think `source` with process substitution makes more sense than `eval` with command substitution.  Either one involves sourcing a foreign script, though.

Comment: Also your solution works if there is a variable with multiple words. You just need to escape `"` character like this: `printf %s\\n "var1=\"$var1\""`

Answer (score 0):

`source <(cat "/path/to/file" | grep "depends\|makedepends")`

The `/path/to/file` is not sourced at all (vs. the approach of Wildcard’s) . See discussion about insecurity above. Also if it is, for example `.env` file of `docker-compose` or similar, it could be used in a such a way to draw variables by other scripts without executing unquoted variables, those which can cause execution errors. For example - `traefik` frontend rule like, `WEB_FRONTEND_RULE=Host:my.host.name;PathPrefix:/my-path-prefix` which is valid in `docker-compose .env` is not valid to be sourced by `bash`. And `WEB_FRONTEND_RULE='Host:my.host.name;PathPrefix:/my-path-prefix'` is valid to be sourced by `bash`, but is not valid in `docker-compose` `.env`.

Answer (score 0):

Source or env both process the whole script, the danger lies in where and who has access to execute it. When you are using it internally it's fine.

On the topic, if you source a script it kind of runs like it was in the same script so your variables will just be set.
So if script 1 is /tmp/script1.sh:

```
a=1
b=2
c=3
```

and script 2 like /tmp/script2.sh

```
source /tmp/script1.sh
echo $a
echo $b
echo $c
```

it will print when run:

1
2
3

For me that is the most common use case, for example when delegating common functionality between scripts (like os detection).

This is perhaps what you mean with pollution, but perhaps you can define the source script with their own vars and this is fine?
It depends a bit on what you really want to achieve.
The eval based answer also 'pollutes' in a similar way but gives you more control.
If you want to reuse data, maybe it is easier to let the scripts you call just write to a text file and use that, or indeed use perl, grep, sed or any other great unixy tool to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/266867/36637) from Wildcard, and after sourcing the file (with all the same caveats around only doing this only if you *trust* the file), we can identify exported variable names by scanning for them, get their declaration and re-export them.

```bash
source-export() {
  local _RC=0
  local FILENAME=$1
  shift
  source <(
    source "${FILENAME}" "$@"
    _RC=$?
    if (( _RC )); then
      typeset -p _RC
      exit
    fi
    # show the exported names
    PATTERN="\b(?<=export)(\s+\w+)+"
    while read -r NAME; do
      [[ -n ${NAME} ]] && typeset -p "${NAME}"
    done < <(grep -oP "${PATTERN}" "${FILENAME}" | tr ' ' '\n')
  )
  return ${_RC}
}
```

Note: the pattern we use to scan for exports should be reasonably robust (handling cases like `export A B`). Another potentially more robust approach would be to diff the variable table pre- and post-sourcing for exported variables.

Example:

```bash
$ cat foo.sh
export XXX="432"
YYY=111
export ZZZ="'adfa $*"
export A B
A=1
B=2
C=3

$ source-export foo.sh 3 2 1
$ echo -e "XXX=$XXX\nYYY=$YYY\nZZZ=$ZZZ\nA=$A\nB=$B\nC=$C"
XXX=432
YYY=
ZZZ='adfa 3 2 1
A=1
B=2
C=
```

versus:

```
$ source foo.sh 3 2 1
$ echo -e "XXX=$XXX\nYYY=$YYY\nZZZ=$ZZZ\nA=$A\nB=$B\nC=$C"
XXX=432
YYY=111
ZZZ='adfa 3 2 1
A=1
B=2
C=3
```

Tested on `bash` and `zsh`.